# Sonar Checkstyle Tag List multiple tags?

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

I am using Checkstyle rule called Tag List in Sonar. Is it possible to define more than one tag in the same rule?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. The [Sonar TagList Plugin documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Taglist+Plugin) has complete instructions including screenshots.

Comment: I have been on that page, but still I cannot find where this is instructed. The page instructs only one tag (TODO) and the NOSONAR, which is part of another rule.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, the `format` property takes a checkstyle regex, which is parsed by [the java.util.regex pattern matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), so you could set it to `TODO|FIXME|WTF`.

Comment: Hi. I added "TODO|FIXME" but only TODO tags were picked up, so the question still remains...

Comment: You are aware that the TagList plugin always labels the piece of the pie chart with `TODO`, even if the individual items might have matched `FIXME`? If you want separate pies, you must use multiple rules.